# Minimizing the expected loss (PRML)

Tags: loss-functions, pattern-recognition, decision-theory, artificial-intelligence

In Bishop's PRML in section 1.5.2, the author introduces a loss function for classification, which is the expected loss,

$$
E[L]=\sum_k \sum_j \int_{R_j} L_{kj}p(\textbf{x},C_k)d\text{x}
$$

where L<sub>kj</sub> is the loss matrix and $p(\textbf{x},C_k)$ is the joint prob distribution of input **x** and the assigned class C<sub>k</sub>.

From that, the author derives that the expected loss for choosing a region R<sub>j</sub> becomes

$$
\sum_kL_{kj}p(C_k|\textbf{x})
$$

How is this derived?

Comment: What about it is unclear to you?

Comment: @Tim I can't seem to figure out how the integration and the p(x) (arising from the p(x,ck) ) vanishes. Does this integrate to 1 over the region? If so, how?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$\mathbf X$ is a random $n$-vector that models the observation $\mathbf x$ in $\mathbb R^n$. The *decision rule* is specified by *partitioning*  $\mathbb R^n$ into disjoint subsets $R_1, R_2, \cdots$: if the observation $\mathbf X$ is an element of $R_j$, then we *decide* or declare that $\mathsf H_j$ is the true hypothesis: $\mathsf H_j$ might or not be the true hypothesis and thus our decision can be in error, or be correct. $L_{k,j}$ is the cost of deciding/declaring that $\mathsf H_j$ is the true hypothesis when in fact, $\mathsf H_k$ is the true hypothesis. Now, Let $f_{\mathbf X\mid \mathsf H_k}(\mathbf x\mid \mathsf H_k)$ denote the *conditional density* of $\mathbf X$ given that $\mathsf H_k$ is the true hypothesis. Then, given that $\mathsf H_k$ is the true hypothesis,
\begin{align}
P(\mathbf X \in R_j\mid \mathsf H_k ) &= P(\text{declare that }R_j~\text{is true when in fact }\mathsf H_k~\text{is true})\\
&= \int_{R_j}_{∣\mathsf H_}(∣\mathsf H_)\, \mathrm d\mathbf x.
\end{align}
Now, declaring that $\mathsf H_j$ is true given that $\mathsf H_k$ is in fact true costs
$L_{k,j}$, and so the average cost of making a decision when $\mathsf H_k$ is the true hypothesis is $\displaystyle \sum_j L_{k,j}\int_{R_j}_{∣\mathsf  H_}(∣\mathsf H_)\, \mathrm d\mathbf x$.  Since the probability that $\mathsf H_k$ is the true hypothesis is $P(\mathsf H_k)$, we incur this cost with probability $P(\mathsf H_k)$, and thus the average loss is
\begin{align}
E[L] &= \sum_k P(\mathsf H_k) \sum_j L_{k,j}\int_{R_j}_{∣\mathsf H_}(∣\mathsf H_)\, \mathrm d\mathbf x\\
&= \sum_k \sum_j L_{k,j}\int_{R_j}_{∣\mathsf  H_}(∣_)\cdot P(\mathsf H_k)\, \mathrm d\mathbf x.
\end{align}
Bishop writes $p(\mathbf x, C_k)$ for what I have written as $ _{∣\mathsf H_}(∣\mathsf H_)\cdot P(\mathsf H_k)$ which is analogous to writing $P(A\mid B)\cdot P(B)$ as $P(A,B)$ instead of the more formal $P(A\cap B)$.

Turning to the OP's question, suppose that we are given that $\mathbf X \in R_j$, and so the *decision* (or declaration or classification) is that $\mathsf H_j$ is the true hypothesis.  If in fact $\mathsf H_k$ is the true hypothesis, then we incur a cost of $L_{k,j}$. So, what is the average cost of deciding that $\mathsf H_j$ is the true hypothesis? Well, we are given that $\mathbf X \in R_j$ and so the average cost of deciding that $\mathsf H_j$ is the true hypothesis is
$$\text{average cost of deciding }\mathsf H_j~\text{is true}
= \sum_k L_{k,j}\cdot P(\mathsf H_k\mid \mathbf X \in R_j). $$
Bishop expresses this as $\displaystyle \sum_k L_{k,j}\cdot P(\mathsf C_k\mid \mathbf x)$ which does not mention the condition that the observation $\mathbf X$ must belong to $R_j$. In my opinion, this lacuna just serves to confuse the issues.